# when I convert unsigned char*(UIImage bytes) to GLuint(textureId) use opengles and invoke c++ method to process it, but result is null

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, avfoundation

I want process cvpixelBuffer(32BGRA format), but I am a beginner of OpenGL, first I am convert cvpixelbuffer to UIImage,get bytes from UIImage, then get a textureId(GLuint), process it...etc, like this code, but result is nil, who can tell me, what happened?

my code like this:

```
- (UIImage *)processVideoFrame:(UIImage *)frame {
   if (!frame) {
       return nil;
    }
    CGFloat width = frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height;
    // convert to unsigned int
    unsigned char *bytes = [frame bytesFromImage];
    unsigned int bgId = createTextureId(width, height, bytes);

    int pixelCount = width * height;
    GLubyte *resultBytes = (GLubyte *)malloc(pixelCount * 4);
    unsigned int textureId = createTextureId(width, height, resultBytes);
    // process video frame
    ovp::ovp_face_beauty_process_texture(handle, textureId, width, height, 0, bgId, true);
    gpuToCpuBuffer(bgId, resultBytes, width, height);
    // unsigned int convert to image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageFromBytes:resultBytes width:width height:height];
    delete bytes;
    delete resultBytes;
    return image;
}


unsigned int createTextureId(int width, int height, unsigned char * ptr) {
    GLuint texId;
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ptr);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return (unsigned int)texId;
}

 /// 将正缓冲区的数据读取到内存中
 /// @param texId 帧缓冲区的内存标识
 /// @param ptr 需要返回的Buffer地址
 /// @param w 宽
 /// @param h 高
void gpuToCpuBuffer(unsigned int texId, unsigned char* ptr, int w, int h) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ptr);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void cpuBufferToGpu(unsigned int textureId, unsigned char *ptr, int w, int h) {
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
//    GLenum err1 = glGetError();
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ptr);
//    GLenum err2 = glGetError();
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

The C++ method is :

```
/// @brief OpenVisionPlatform for vedio real-time
/// targetId : output image texture ID
/// width : image width
/// height : image height
/// rotate : CW_ROTATE_0 = 0 by default, CW_ROTATE_90 = 1, CW_ROTATE_180 = 2, CW_ROTATE_270 = 3
/// bgId : input image texture ID
/// needMirror : x-axis flip,true by default
OVP_API_EXPORT ovp_status_t ovp_face_beauty_process_texture( ovp_handle_t handle, unsigned int targetId, int width, int height, unsigned int rotate, unsigned int bgId = 0, bool needMirror = true );
```

Comment: Now, I know where I went wrong.The C++ lib was used to iOS and Andriod, It need a opengles context, param is 'X3DGlobalContext'

Comment: ```class OVP_API_EXPORT X3DGlobalContext {
    public:
        X3DGlobalContext();
        ~X3DGlobalContext();
        X3DGlobalContext(X3DGlobalContext&&) noexcept;
        X3DGlobalContext& operator=(X3DGlobalContext&&) noexcept;
        ovp_status_t Init( const EffectInitArgs& args);
        ovp_status_t SetLogCallback(LogCallbackType callback, void* userParam);
        ovp_status_t RemoveLogCallback();
        ovp_status_t SetDefaultLogCallback();
    private:
        struct Impl;
        std::unique_ptr<Impl> mImpl;
        friend class X3DEffect;
    };```

Comment: but how to init the  X3DGlobalContext? 